# Getting "The 'WhatEver' view or its master could not be found" with Spark View Engine when going to the login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, yellow-screen-of-death

Uff...long title.

As it states, when the asp.net redirects to the login page, it adds the ?RequestUrl=/pathToSome/Action to the url. When this happens I get that YSOD :"The view '/PathToSome/Action' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:"

Any thoughts on why?

Thanks
Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied answer from [Spark discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/d92a7bc6989ff44f))

Should be fine - if you start with a stock "new ASP.NET MVC project"
and convert the views to spark it has the same type of url in the
login page and works fine.

In the login action when you return View(x); could the request url be
passed in accidentally as x?